# filter function shows an empty array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to create a search filter. The way it works is a user inputs a text in the search bar, the input is stored using vuex and the result is shown in a different page. Here's an array of objects in a js file

```
export const productData = [
   {
     id: 1,
     name: "table",
     materials: "wood"
   },
   {
     id: 2,
     name: "table2",
     materials: "metal"
   },
   {
     id: 3,
     name: "chair",
     materials: "plastic"
   }
]
```

I want to filter using the user's input. Here's my function

```
import { productData } from '@/data/productData'

export default {
data() {
   return {
      products: productData
   }
},
computed: {
   userInput() {
      return this.$store.state.userInput
   },
   filterProducts: function() {
      return this.products.filter(q => q.name.match(this.userInput))
   }
}
}
```

When I console the userInput, it works fine! So the problem is in the filterProducts function. It shows an empty array if I console it. What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

edit: the reason I make a new variable called products is because the actual js file is more complex so I had to flatten the array. But the flatten process works fine so I thought I would just simplify the question.

Comment: Working on my side. Could you confirm what you do have in the `userInput` computed ?Also, where are your `products`, in `data` ?

Comment: Is your `products` a const outside the component? I believe it is not in `data`. Try filtering like this: `products.filter(q => q.name.match(this.userInput))`

Comment: @kissu umm, it's imported from another js file.. wait let me update my question to make it clearer

Comment: @AdriSolid yes, it's from another js file. wait let me update my question

Comment: Still working totally fine on my side. If your `userInput` is properly populated (no async data or alike) and there are no side effects, it should work as intended. Working great with the exact same code. Maybe check the location of the file and look into the devtools to see if `products` is filled properly.

Comment: @kissu ah yes, so sorryy, I think it's my mistake. I thought that if I only type a word or a part of the `name` string, it would also work. If I wanna do it, what method should I use?

Comment: You can try it in the chrome devtools console, create a products variable and run `products.filter(q => q.name.match('ta'))`, it will give you 2 elements, so `match` is fine here. The issue is somewhere else.

Comment: @kissu Alright, will do it! Thank you so much for your help! Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

The match function accepts a [regex](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp), not String. Give indexOf a try:

```
filterProducts: function() {
   return this.products.filter(q => q.name.indexOf(this.userInput) >= 0)
}
```

Comment: It is working great tbh. "If regexp is a non-RegExp object, it is implicitly converted to a RegExp by using new RegExp(regexp)" >> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#parameters Rather not use an old `indexOf`..